# Bootstrap collapse

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, twitter-bootstrap

Estou criando uma lista usando o `collapse` em uma interação de `loop`, porém estão todos iniciando aberto, gostaria que somente o primeiro item do meu `collapse` ficasse aberto.

Se clicar duas vezes em um dos itens, ele fecha todos os outros, ficando aberto só o que foi clicado.

Minha view

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    @for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading_@i">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse_@i" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse_@i"
                       @{ if (i == 0) { <text> collapse</text>} else { <text></text>}}>
                        Collapsible Group Item #@i
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse_@i" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading_@i">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Editado conforme sugestão do Luis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a solução é alterar o div:

```
<div id="collapse_@i" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading_@i">
```

para

```
<div id="collapse_@i" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading_@i">
```

removento o estilo `in`

o estilo `in` faz com que o elemento onde ele é usado, fique visível, como pode ser visto na sua definição que é encontrado dentro do arquivo `bootstrap.css`

```
.collapse.in {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: @rman, não sou expert em css, mas acho que dei uma esclarecida com o que adicionei na resposta.

Comment: Então, é mais para a resposta não ficar tão "seca" mesmo. Com certeza a explicação agora ajuda (: - (vou apagar meus comentários para não "sujar" a resposta).

Answer (score -1):

Não sei ao certo onde você define que o elemento deve ser collapse, mas coloque um `(i == 0) ? 'collapse' : '';`. Não deve ser a melhor solução, mas resolve seu problema.

Comment: Luis, não resolveu, já atualizei o meu código da minha view conforme propôs.

Comment: Descoberto o problema, tem que tirar o `in` do `class` do `div` antes do `panel-body`.